# htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Well i have this code into my .htaccess file

```
  Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on

    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ (.+)\.php  [NC]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/?admincp/?((.)|(\.)*)
    RewriteRule [^/php/error\.php] /php/error.php  [L,NS]

    # Otherwise check if root request and rewrite to /php/index.php
    RewriteRule ^(/?)$ /php/index.php  [L,NS]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\.php$  [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/?admincp/?((.)|(\.)*)
    RewriteRule ^([a-z|_]+)/?$ /php/index.php?categorie=$1 [L,NC,NS]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\.php$  [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/?admincp/?(.*)
    RewriteRule ^([a-z|_]+)/([a-z|_|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9]+)/?$ /php/index.php?categorie=$1&subcategorie=$2 [L,NC,NS]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/?admincp/?(.*)
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\.php$  [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([a-z|_]+)/([a-z|_|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ /php/index.php?categorie=$1&subcategorie=$2&article=$3 [L,NC,NS]
    ErrorDocument 404 /php/index.php?categorie=apps&subcategorie=error404
```

I am trying to change line 6 to this:

```
  RewriteRule [^/php/index\.php\?categorie=apps&subcategorie=error404] /php/index.php?categorie=apps&subcategorie=error404  [L,NS]
```

but it doesn't work..
When i type `http://localhost/php/index.php` i see this page, but i don't want to see this page..I want to see `http://localhost/php/index.php?categorie=apps&subcategorie=error404`

Any help?

Comment: This should be line 7 if you are counting blank lines! Is that right?

Comment: @Khaled yes!!of course

Comment: Any advice guys?

Answer (score 1):

I think the rule should be:

```
RewriteRule !/php/index\.php\?categorie=apps&subcategorie=error404  /php/index.php?categorie=apps&subcategorie=error404  [L,NS]
```

The pattern `[^...]` means any single character except the ones listed after `^`. The `!` means negate the entire pattern.

Comment: `Internal Server Error` thx for the response

Comment: In `.htaccess` the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` directive never starts with a slash (and neither does it contain a query string) - so this _negated_ regex will _always_ be successful, which will likely result in a rewrite loop (ie. "Internal Server Error").

Answer (score 0):

The `RewriteRule` directive matches against the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string. In a `.htaccess` (*directory*) context this URL-path does not start with a slash either, since the directory-prefix is first removed.

Checking that the "full URL" is *not* an exact match for a URL-path + query-string is not quite so trivial in mod_rewrite. You would need to do everything with `RewriteCond` directives and either use two OR'd *conditions*, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/php/index\.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^categorie=apps&subcategorie=error404$
RewriteRule ^ /php/index.php?categorie=apps&subcategorie=error404  [L,NS]
```

However, by itself, the above does not necessarily protect against an internal rewrite loop if you have other directives rewriting the URL.

Alternatively, you can use a single *condition* and check against `THE_REQUEST` server variable. This will also protect against any potential rewrite loops since `THE_REQUEST` is not updated when the URL is rewritten. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /php/index\.php\?categorie=apps&subcategorie=error404\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^ /php/index.php?categorie=apps&subcategorie=error404  [L,NS]
```